# Stop the text moving down on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a text in the middle of the div block with a font size 80px. When I hover on the div block, it will change the border size from 1px to 5px with a blue color but the text will moves down.

```css
.calendar-content {
  width: 81%;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}

.calendarday-container {
  width: 139px;
  height: 139px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.calendarday-add .calendarday-number {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 12px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.calendarday-number:hover {
  margin: 12px 2px;
}

.calendarday-container:hover {
  border: 5px solid #2e7ad1;
}

.add-day-ico {
  display: none;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  margin: 22px 0px;
  float: right;
}

.calendarday-container:hover .add-day-ico {
  display: block;
  margin: 22px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendarday-container" data-day="0" data-dropable="true">
  <a href="/autoresponder/create_day.php?day=0" data-action="click" class="calendarday-add">
    <span class="calendarday-number">0</span>
    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/u/F/K/J/M/A/add-button-md.png" sytle="height: 21px; width: 21px;" align="right" style="margin-top: 3px;" class="add-day-ico">
  </a>

</div>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f0k6r9nb/

I have tried to change the margin in the `calendarday-container:hover .add-day-ico` but it didn't help to resolve the issue.

Can you please show me an example how I can stop the text moving down on hover?

Thank you.

Comment: The border in `.calendarday-container:hover` is causing it to move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical approach to showing a border on hover is to have the non-hover state be transparent or a color that matches the background along with the width matching that of the border when hovered.

In this case, there's an existing `1px` border. Here, I would change the gray border blue, then use an inset `box-shadow` to add the additional `4px` of the border.

**Note:** I also removed some margin for `.calendarday-number` on hover so the number does not shift.

```css
.calendar-content {
  width: 81%;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}

.calendarday-container {
  width: 139px;
  height: 139px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.calendarday-add .calendarday-number {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 12px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* 
.calendarday-number:hover {
  margin: 12px 2px;
}
*/

.calendarday-container:hover {
  border-color: #2e7ad1;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #2e7ad1;
}

.add-day-ico {
  display: none;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  margin: 22px 0px;
  float: right;
}

.calendarday-container:hover .add-day-ico {
  display: block;
  margin: 22px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendarday-container" data-day="0" data-dropable="true">
  <a href="/autoresponder/create_day.php?day=0" data-action="click" class="calendarday-add">
    <span class="calendarday-number">0</span>
    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/u/F/K/J/M/A/add-button-md.png" sytle="height: 21px; width: 21px;" align="right" style="margin-top: 3px;" class="add-day-ico">
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for this as this is what I really want. Problem are now resolved! :)

Answer (score 3):

Changing the width of the border from 1px to 5px and recalculating the inner parts is not a practical solution. You could use an additional element, which has 5px of transparent border and change it to 5px of colored border on hover.

Another simple solution would be to use `outline` instead, as it doesn't add to the elements dimensions:

```css
.calendar-content {
  width: 81%;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}

.calendarday-container {
  width: 139px;
  height: 139px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.calendarday-container:hover {
  outline: 5px solid #2e7ad1;
}

.calendarday-add .calendarday-number {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 12px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.add-day-ico {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.calendarday-container:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendarday-container" data-day="0" data-dropable="true">
  <a href="/autoresponder/create_day.php?day=0" data-action="click" class="calendarday-add">
    <span class="calendarday-number">0</span>
    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/u/F/K/J/M/A/add-button-md.png" class="add-day-ico">
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for this but I need to display the image on a hover. Can you add the image on a hover please? thank you!

Comment: Not part of the question, but here you go. It also makes more sense to position the icon image absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
.calendarday-container {
        border: 5px solid transparent;
        outline: 1px solid #ccc;
        outline: none;
   }

.calendarday-container:hover {
        outline: none;
   }
```

Remove this:

```
.calendarday-number:hover {
       margin: 12px 2px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The text was moving down because, There was increase in `border-width` from `1px` to `5px` while hover.

You can either maintain a outline around the box using `outline` property, and keeping the `border: 5px solid transparent` to `border: 5px solid #2e7ad1` while hovering.

I've created a working fiddle for you, for better understanding: [Link to Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Baliga/f0k6r9nb/21/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pseudo element like this. I also removed lot of unnecessary css that was fighting each other

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
body { margin: 5%; }

/* Normal */
.calendarday-container { 
 width: 150px; height: 150px; 
 position: relative; 
 display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; 
}
.calendarday-container:after { 
 content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; 
 border: 1px solid #ccc; z-index: -1; 
}

.caldndarday-add  { text-decoration: none; }
.calendarday-number { font-size: 80px; color: #ccc; }
.add-day-ico   { width: 24px; height: 24px; position: absolute; bottom: -8px; right: -8px; }

/* Hover FX */
.calendarday-container:hover:after      { border: 10px solid navy; }
.calendarday-container:hover .calendarday-number  { color: navy; }
```

```html
<div class="calendarday-container" data-day="0" data-dropable="true">
 <a class="caldndarday-add" href="/autoresponder/create_day.php?day=0" data-action="click">
  <span class="calendarday-number">0</span>
  <img class="add-day-ico" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/u/F/K/J/M/A/add-button-md.png">
 </a>
</div>
```